# selinux, grub-pc, sda: what to do?

Tags: 16.04, grub2, selinux

I wanted to install `selinux` on Ubuntu 16.04. The system asked me to install grub-pc:

[image: 1]

Since I don't know which option I should select, I looked for similar issues on the web and I noticed I don't have `/dev/sda`.

Could someone explain me what I am supposed to do and why I don't have `/dev/sda`?

Comment: You have the newer NVMe SSD drive and your install is LVM with encryption. Grub-pc is for BIOS boot, almost all new NVMe drives are on newer UEFI systems using UEFI boot. But you are not showing an ESP - efi system partition, so maybe BIOS/CSM/Legacy install.

Answer (score 0):

You have dm-0, dm-1 etc. By device mapper in the kernel, used by LVM.

cmd:

```
dmsetup ls
```

to find out which is /dev/sda.